# segmentation fault with nano editor in command line with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, sudo, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04. My command line text editors such as `nano` or `pico` can no longer run as a user in the command line, I get

```
user@hostname:~$ nano 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, things work when I do it with sudo `sudo nano`, `sudo pico` etc...
I do not have this problem with `vi`

Since last time it worked, I made the routine updates from Ubuntu, and installed a couple virtual environments with `conda`. I also edited my LD_LIBRARY_PATH for tensorflow running with CUDA toolkit:

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

`/usr/local/cuda-11.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/home/rattie/miniconda3/lib/`

[UPDATE] It looks like this LD_LIBRARY_PATH edited for tensorflow is the culprit. I was editing it in the conda base environment, instead of isolating that change in a virtual environment created for using tensorflow (e.g. via `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh`)
In particular, removing `/home/rattie/miniconda3/lib/` fixed the issue, although I do not understand why it was causing my commands such as nano to require sudo privileges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem come from a library conflict or incompatibility issue, you should set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only for the specific virtual environments that require it like TensorFlow or CUDA.

lets do an environment activation script in the virtual environment for that:

first lets create a new directory `mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d` then we create a file env_vars.sh  `touch $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh` and add this inside:

```
#!/bin/sh
export OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/home/rattie/miniconda3/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then save and we will create a deactivation script to restore the original `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d
```

then we create a file env_vars.sh in it `touch $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh`

open it and add:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Save and try again, the conflict error should be solved

Comment: This is what I thought I had done at the beginning, by following tensorflow's documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip 
But I must have skipped a step because my $CONDA_PREFIX was still pointing at the base environment instead of the conda virtual environment for tensorflow.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue while working on a SLURM cluster with a module-loaded programs. Until the admin looks into it and implements a proper fix, appending: `alias nano='LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" command nano'` to my `.bashrc` file works as a bodge